# How to select multiple column names in specific one level with Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There is a DataFrame which has a MultipleIndex as column.
I know I can use `.xs()` like a following code, when I want to select only one column name and level name.

```
df.xs('column_name1', level='column_level1', axis=1)
```

In my specific case, I want to select multiple column names like following code.
(Actually It doesn't work, because .xs doesn't support this way.)

```
df.xs(['column_name1', 'column_name2'], level='column_level1', axis=1)
```

How to select multiple column names in specific one level?

---

I show more specific code.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = u"""
column_name1,column_name2,column_name3
column_nameA,column_nameB,column_nameC
0.1,1,10
0.2,2,20
0.3,3,30
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), header=[0, 1])
df.columns.names = ['column_level1', 'column_level2']
print df
```

`df` is this

```
column_level1 column_name1 column_name2 column_name3
column_level2 column_nameA column_nameB column_nameC
0                      0.1            1           10
1                      0.2            2           20
2                      0.3            3           30
```

and, I want to make this data by column name

```
column_level1 column_name1 column_name2
column_level2 column_nameA column_nameB
0                      0.1            1
1                      0.2            2
2                      0.3            3
```

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You can try: `df.xs(('column_name1', 'column_name2'), level='column_level1', axis=1)`

Comment: It leads error `KeyError: ('column_name1', 'column_name2')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`select`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select.html):

```
print df.select(lambda x: x[0] in ['column_name1','column_name2'], axis=1)

column_level1 column_name1 column_name2
column_level2 column_nameA column_nameB
0                      0.1            1
1                      0.2            2
2                      0.3            3
```

Or [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values('column_level1')
                          .isin(['column_name1','column_name2'])]

column_level1 column_name1 column_name2
column_level2 column_nameA column_nameB
0                      0.1            1
1                      0.2            2
2                      0.3            3
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use `loc` with `slice` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#cross-section):

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]:
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux  
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one  two
0      -0.313815 -0.160567 -0.028432 -1.169930  1.043274  0.353722 -0.912303 -1.041827
1      -0.317570 -0.452766  0.950578  0.467092 -1.960936  1.700110  0.003934  0.989709
2       0.091249  2.406773  1.848771 -1.275288  0.740245  0.657444 -1.157392 -0.103663

In [59]: df.loc[:, (['bar', 'baz'], slice(None))]
Out[59]:
first        bar                 baz
second       one       two       one       two
0      -0.313815 -0.160567 -0.028432 -1.169930
1      -0.317570 -0.452766  0.950578  0.467092
2       0.091249  2.406773  1.848771 -1.275288
```

For second level:

```
In [68]: df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['one', 'two'])]
Out[68]:
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux  
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
0      -0.313815 -0.160567 -0.028432 -1.169930  1.043274  0.353722 -0.912303 -1.041827
1      -0.317570 -0.452766  0.950578  0.467092 -1.960936  1.700110  0.003934  0.989709
2       0.091249  2.406773  1.848771 -1.275288  0.740245  0.657444 -1.157392 -0.103663
```

**EDIT**

For your dataframe:

```
In [75]: df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['column_nameA', 'column_nameB'])]
Out[75]:
column_level1 column_name1 column_name2
column_level2 column_nameA column_nameB
0                      0.1            1
1                      0.2            2
2                      0.3            3

In [77]: df.loc[:, (['column_name1', 'column_name2'], slice(None))]
Out[77]:
column_level1 column_name1 column_name2
column_level2 column_nameA column_nameB
0                      0.1            1
1                      0.2            2
2                      0.3            3
```

Comment: I did this code `df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['column_name1', 'column_name2'])]`. but the result has no data.

Comment: Because that for second level and you don't have `column_name1` and `column_name2` in that level which is expected to give empty data. You need to slice it for 1st level, or change you column_names to `column_nameA` and `column_nameB`